# Create flag if customer ordered in the next month / If total of a column for the next weeks is more than 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
    CUSTOMER    WEEK NO  ORDERS
0   Ann         4        1
1   Ann         6        3
2   John        1        1
3   John        7        2
```

I`d like to add a Flag column that indicates if the customer made an order in the next month / within the next 4 weeks.  My ideal output would be something like this:

```
    CUSTOMER    WEEK NO  ORDERS  FLAG
0   Ann         4        1       1
1   Ann         6        3       0
2   John        1        1       0
3   John        7        2       0
```

I looked at some examples on this site and derived this code.  It seems to work on a few accounts but when I apply to the whole dataframe, everything is flagged as 1.  I'm not sure why, I even added the Customer condition but again, when applied to the whole dataframe it doesn`t work:

```
df['Flag'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df.loc[(df.Week_No >= x.Week_No) &
                        (df.Week_No <= x.Week_No+4) & (x.Customer==df.Customer), 'total_orders'].sum()>=1
                        else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic used to wether the user has a flag or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `CUSTOMER`, find the differences between `WEEK NO`s, and then shift the results back to line up how we want. If these differences are `<=4`, the mask will be `True`.

```
df['FLAG'] = 0
mask = df.groupby('CUSTOMER')['WEEK NO'].diff().shift(-1).le(4)
df['FLAG'].mask(mask, 1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  CUSTOMER  WEEK NO  ORDERS  FLAG
0      Ann        4       1     1
1      Ann        6       3     0
2     John        1       1     0
3     John        7       2     0
```

Comment: This works amazingly and it`s much quicker than my current code, thank you! Do you mind if I ask how the shift and le functions work here please?

Comment: `shift(-1)` Shifts each group's index by back one, For exactly what's happening you can break my code up into pieces. Run just `df.groupby('CUSTOMER')['WEEK NO'].diff()` and then run `df.groupby('CUSTOMER')['WEEK NO'].diff().shift(-1)` to see the difference~

Comment: `le(4)` is a shortcut for saying *less than or equal to 4* and would be equivalent to `...).shift(-1) <= 4`. Using the shortcuts `le()`, `lt()`, `eq()`, `gt()`, `ge()` etc. allows for easier chaining of functions, and is (imo) better practice.

Comment: You can check out [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html#pandas-dataframe-le) "Equivalent to ==, !=, <=, <, >=, > with support to choose axis (rows or columns) and level for comparison."